# В какой момент идет подгрузка изображений?

Tags: html, css

Допустим у меня есть несколько превью-картинок на странице. При нажатии, отображаются картинка полностью.

```
<a rel="lightbox[flat]" href="">
<img src="">
</a>
<a rel="lightbox[flat]" href="">
<img src="">
</a>
<a rel="lightbox[flat]" href="">
<img src="">
</a>
```

1. Загрузка картинки в полном объеме начинается только при нажатии на превью, или она уже сразу загружается в ДОМ?
2. Если картинка лежит в блоке div, и див display:none, то картинка все равно загружается клиентом?

Хотелось бы добиться более быстрой загрузки страницы.

Comment: Можно использовать lazyload, в display:none картинка всё равно грузится.

Comment: Как я понял lazyload только для скроллинга подходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Лайтбокс по умолчанию, на сколько я помню, грузит все, что видно. Другое дело, это все равно происходит ПОСЛЕ загрузки ДОМа. После щелчка происходит подгрузка того, что не видно.

2) да, она грузится. Но тоже после ДОМА:)

Для ускорения загрузки в первую очередь стоит избавиться от обращений к сторонним сайтам - яваскрипт у гугла, счетчики, картинки на левых сайтах.

Comment: Хочу реализовать следующее:
есть картинка. при нажатии на нее появляется другая. И так все картинки, которые находятся в массиве лайтбокса. 
Неизвестно будет ли нажимать клиент на все картинки. Поэтому хотелось бы подгружать только первую А остальные по щелчкам.

Comment: Лучше подгружать N-ную и N+1, N-1. Тогда при нажатии смена будет происходть мгновенно. Для ускорения - N, N+2, N+1, N-1

Comment: Т.е. для  N+1, N-1 создать display:block и раскрывать его при щелчке?
Или получше алгоритм есть?)
А для других просто джаваскриптом добавлять новые <a rel="lightbox[flat]" href="">
<img src="">
</a> ?

Comment: Для кэшированных можно просто создавать объект класса img, не привязанный к dom. Можно и display:block, конечно